# Adding tooltip for icon in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Can anyone help how to add tooltip for an UiHandler using GWT in java

Thanks in advance,

Raj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
button.setTitle(tooltip);
```

Read the documentation at http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setTitle-java.lang.String-

Comment: Hi @Soufiane Hassou,@krishnakumarp thanks for the suggestion.can you please tell how to set message in two languages.As my application is in two languages, i want to set tooltip message in two languages.

Comment: You can use GWT I18N framework to internationalize the message. Read more at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n and https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n